# Reapeating text in discord.js idk if its due to using ms or ive messed up somewhere | Glitch, Discord.js (I use glitch)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So basically 
My code is here
https://hastebin.com/ibafulayoj.js
I use MS for delays Dscord.js for well bots and glitch to keep my bot up
I need help with the messages being sent constantly everytime a user messages After the command is used havoc begins

Answer (score 0):

You most likely started your bot twice. Did you use cmd or a terminal in like VSC? Try closing them all.

Comment: Wdym? Close and re-open the app?

Comment: I think i started it 4 times it says "Ready!" 4 times

Comment: Yes the whole app. You can test if the problem why your bot is sending multiple messages is because you've accidentally started it twice by simply shutting the bot down in your current terminal. If it then still responds to your messages in Discord it's still operating somewhere. (notice that it now is sending only 1 message!)
At least that was what happened to me a few times.

Comment: OKi how do i shut it down in the terminal though sorry

Comment: Usually Ctrl + C

Comment: Indeed, it should! Now your bot is offline, does it still respond to your messages in Discord while it's "offline"?

Comment: Yeah it still does,

Comment: Well in that case it's excatly the problem I meant. Do you use Visual Studio Code or something else? In any case, close your code editor and any other Terminals like cmd/shell or whatever there's currently running on your Pc.

Comment: I use glitch.com to keep my bot online and I've tried that

Comment: ahh it's not running on your own Pc

Comment: Nope its not. I could switch to visual studio I do have it but like its very confusing

Comment: glitch.com rather looks confusing to me ^^' Does it just host your bot for free?

Comment: Yeah it does, Im not to sure how to host a bot on visual studio though

Comment: by simply typing "node *<your main js file>*" in the terminal. Like **node bot.js** or **node bot.js**

Comment: but then your Pc has to be on all the time. Didn't know there where sites hosting bots for free

Comment: Nah the tab has to alwasy be open so its kinda the same thing

Comment: Makes sense. Now back to the topic, what happened when you closed the tab? Did your bot still respond to you?

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: Well if it's running on your own Pc closing your browser or restarting your Pc should stop it. If not: stop using glitch 

Comment: Oki! Lmao, Honestly studio is probs easier

Comment: Yup i think its glitch Imma switch to studio